# Clear react multi-select/async

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using the async multi-selector from the following:

https://react-select.com/home#async

It works perfectly, but I would like to clear the selector after pressing any button:
[image]

The red-marked "X" clears the selector, but I truly don't know how to use it.
This is my code:

```js
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Async, { makeAsyncSelect } from "react-select/async";
class AppSelector extends React.Component {

  appList = [];

  state = {
    selectedOption: null
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.appList = JSON.parse(localStorage.appList);
  };

  handleChange = (newValue, actionMeta) => {
    this.props.getAppSelectorValue(newValue);
  };

  getOptions = () => {
    let temp = [];
    let appArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.appList);
    // console.log('in get options',appArr)
    appArr.map(obj => {
      obj.value = obj.id;
      obj.label = obj.product;
      delete obj.id;
      delete obj.product;
      temp.push(obj);
    });
    return temp;
  };

  render() {
    let appArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.appList);
    let appList = [];
    appArr.map(obj => {
      obj.value = obj.id;
      obj.label = obj.product;
      delete obj.id;
      delete obj.product;
      appList.push(obj);
    });
    // console.log('in render',appList)
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="appSelector">
        <Async
          loadOptions={this.getOptions}
          defaultOptions={appList}
          cacheOptions
          isMulti
          inputValue={selectedOption}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AppSelector;
```

The component is being called at the main component (named "Home"):

```
appSelectorHTML=()=>
    {
        let htmlArr=[];

        if(localStorage.appList)
        {
            // if(this.state.selectorRefresh===false)
            htmlArr.push(
                <AppSelector
                selectorRefresh={this.state.selectorRefresh}
                appList={this.state.appList}
                getAppSelectorValue={this.getAppSelectorValue}
                ></AppSelector>
            )
        }

        else
        {
            window.location.reload();
            // this.appSelectorHTML(); 
        }
        return htmlArr
    }
```

The props function in the main component:

```
getAppSelectorValue=(selectedApps)=>
    {
        this.selectedApps=selectedApps;
    }
```

The send form function:

```
sendForm=()=>
    {
     this.toggleModal();
     let newNetworks=this.createNetworks(this.newNetworks,this.selectedApps)
     let addArr=[...this.state.cashedNetworks].concat(newNetworks);
     let convertedNetworks=this.relationshipDisplay(addArr)
     sessionStorage.newNetworks=JSON.stringify(convertedNetworks);
     this.setState({cashedNetworks:convertedNetworks}); 
     }
```

Thank you for the helpers!

Comment: Does setting `this.appList = []` work?

Comment: set the appList  array to blank

Comment: It doesn't work.
I also have to mention that there is a function called "sendForm" at the main component, which is executed when clicking on one of the buttons.

Comment: What about setting selectedOption to empty? I'm confused, is the selected values controlled or not?